# Need assistance getting Bootstrap 3 Scrollspy to work with auto-collapsing mobile menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

The issue I am having is getting both Scrollspy and a mobile menu to collapse when a link is clicked together.  I can get the functionality of either one working by itself, but not together.

This snippet has scrollspy working, however, the mobile menu does not collapse when a linked is clicked.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mainNavbar">
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Name</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#social-media">Social</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

If I add the following to each anchor tag the mobile menu will collapse on click, but scrollspy breaks:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"
```

I'm assuming that using data-target is causing the issue, but I'm not sure how else to get around it.

Does anybody know of a way to get these two things to work together?

In searching other answers I was able to get both features to work by themselves, but I've yet been able to find something to assist in getting them working together.  If I missed an answer, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching, it seems like using the data-toggle and data-target in the anchor tags breaks scrollspy.  I've decided to use the following JS I found on another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877429/twitter-bootstrap-mobile-nav-hide-menu-after-clicking-menu-link) for collapsing the mobile nav menu.  This doesn't work with sub-menus it seems, but I'm not worried about that.

```
    <script>
      $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
      });
    </script>
```