# preventing bootstrap collapse animation above md breakpoint

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've created a website using Bootstrap. My site has a navigation bar, and the menu options 'About', 'My Projects', and 'Contact Me' hide behind an expandable menu when the webpage width is less than the md breakpoint. I've added data-toggle="collapse" to the menu options so that when the user clicks any of the menu options, the menu collapses.

The problem I'm encountering is that the menu options mentioned above go through the collapse animation even when the width of the page is above the md breakpoint.

One way I feel this behavior could be manipulated is by adding/removing the data-toggle="collapse" attribute based on the current size of the page through use of $(window).resize() and $(window).load() event listeners for the initial load of the page.

Could there be a better solution though?

Link to website: http://benws-projectportfolio.herokuapp.com/

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color:#3A4A4D;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ben Shippey</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mr-auto" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="background-color:#3A4A4D;">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="aboutButton" class="nav-link active" href="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="projectButton" class="nav-link" href="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse">My Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="contactButton" class="nav-link" href="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: One way would also be to force the height: auto!important; on the element on md screen and higher. Will have some issues if it has padding and margin. But there is also a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this answer from @ZimSystem with success: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684484/6252145

Add data-target attribute to your nav links. In your case though, it would be:

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
```

instead of

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"
```

as in @ZimSystem's answer

Comment: thanks, but the problem with this solution is that the menu will no longer collapse when the page is below the md breakpoint

Comment: @BenWS, sorry if I misunderstood - is this not the functionality you're  [looking for ?](https://www.screencast.com/t/fLv4cogjV) It works in safari & ff as well, didn't check ie/edge

Comment: apologies @plumsauced1, after testing again - this seems to work perfectly. thanks!